# How to read/listen windows notification popup by python

Tags: python, windows

I made a script to listen windows10 popup notification by python. It worked. But I changed my laptop and set up same environment and then I got error message.

windows10
python 3.10.10
winsdk library

this is my script.

```
from winsdk.windows.ui.notifications.management import UserNotificationListener
from winsdk.windows.ui.notifications import KnownNotificationBindings


verification_number = None


def handler(a, b):
    global verification_number
    unotification = a.get_notification(b.user_notification_id)
    # print(dir(unotification))
    if hasattr(unotification, "app_info"):
        # print("App Name: ", unotification.app_info.display_info.display_name)
        text_sequence = unotification.notification.visual.get_binding(KnownNotificationBindings.get_toast_generic()).get_text_elements()
        it = iter(text_sequence)
        # print("Notification title: ", it.current.text)
        while True:
            next(it, None)
            if it.has_current:
                if "varification" in it.current.text:
                    verification_number = it.current.text[-6:-1]
                    print(verification_number)
            else:
                break            
    else:
        pass

    
listener = UserNotificationListener.get_current()
listener.add_notification_changed(handler)
```

this is the error message.

listener.add_notification_changed(handler)
OSError: [WinError -2147023728] no element found

Comment: The error message indicates that the UserNotificationListener cannot be found on the new laptop. It could be because the User Notification Service is not running or there is a compatibility issue with the operating system version. You could try checking the Windows Event Viewer for any related errors and also make sure that the User Notification Service is running. Additionally, you could try running the script as an administrator to see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: @Sullivan I checked windows event viewer and I found  User Notification Service is working.

Comment: Check your notification settings, Restart your computer, or log out and log back, and If you have done these things and it still doesn't work, try another computer